# Sending an ArrayBuffer in PHP through JavaScript XHR2 object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, arraybuffer

Here it is, I'm writing the new version of an AJAX library based on promises with XHR2 support (https://github.com/pyrsmk/qwest). I'm currently writing the unit tests and 95% of the library is now robust. Anyway, I need to verify that we can successfully retrieve an ArrayBuffer (XHR2 supports 'arraybuffer' response type) but how can I generate this ArrayBuffer with PHP? What protocol do I use? Base64?

I really have no idea how I should handle the whole thing...

EDIT : it seems that when I send an ArrayBuffer to PHP, the data is handled directly by the $_POST variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Intro

Well, you don't send an "ArrayBuffer". What you send is data and specify a format to make sense of that data. The client, then, can choose the best way to interpret it.

So, **an ArrayBuffer is just a generic fixed-length container for data (binary data)** that enables you to create "views" of the underlying data using JavaScript typed arrays. The cool thing is that multiple views can be created from a single ArrayBuffer source.

---

That being said, in your specific case, you can send binary data in PHP the same way you send any data in PHP.

### Example:

#### server.php

```
$filename = 'img.png';
$fsize = filesize($filename);

$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, $fsize);
fclose($handle);

header('content-type: image/png');
header('Content-Length: ' . $fsize);

echo $contents;
```

or shorter

```
$filename = 'img.png';

header('content-type: image/png');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));

readfile($filename);
```

---

#### client.js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'server.php', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    console.log(uInt8Array);
};

xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling binary data in php is a little bit tricky. To response an ArrayBuffer you must cast it to a binary string and result it with an **echo** statement.

To generate a binary string from an 8 bit array, it is necessary to use the **pack** statement. If the server does not support PHP version 5.6+, each array item can be converted and concat with the dot operator:

**server.php**

```
<?php
    header('content-type: application/octet-stream');

    $arrayBuffer = array(0, 1, 2, 253, 254, 255);

    $binary = "";
    for($index = 0; $index < count($arrayBuffer); $index++)
    {
        $binary = $binary.pack("C*", $arrayBuffer[$index]);
    }

    echo $binary;
?>
```

The MIME type of raw data is *application/octet-stream*. At client side of the JavaScript code looks like:

**client.js**

```
let xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlRequest.open('POST', 'server.php');
xmlRequest.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xmlRequest.onload = event =>
{
    let arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(event.target.response);
    console.log('arrayBuffer: ', arrayBuffer); // [0, 1, 2, 253, 254, 255];
};
xmlRequest.send();
```